# Why does a "division by zero" occur here?

Tags: c, runtime-error, cs50, divide-by-zero

I've been trying to find the length of a given number using this program, however I get the following error every time I run it:

check_length.c:16:26: runtime error: division by zero

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void check_length(long);

int main(void)
{
     long c = get_long("Enter Number: ");
     check_length(c);
}

void check_length(long w)
{
      for(int i=1;i<=16;i++)
      {
            int scale = w/((10)^i);
            if (scale<10 && scale>0)
            {
                 int length = i+1;
                 printf("%i\n",length);
            }
       }    
}
```

Comment: `^` isn't exponentiation in C.

Comment: Does the fact that it breaks when i = 10 mean nothing to you?

Comment: `(10)^10` is `10 XOR 10` is `0b1010 XOR 0b1010` is `0b0000`, i.e. division by zero. Look for `pow` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is that the operator `^` isn't doing what you expect. It seems you expect it to raise 10 to the power of `i` but `^` is actually the bitwise XOR operator.

So when `i` is 10, you do `10 XOR 10` which is zero. Therefore the division by zero.

You could take a look at the `pow` function instead but why make things that complicated?

Simply keep diving by 10 until you get zero and then return the number of divisions.

Something like this for non-negative values:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int check_length(unsigned long w)
{
    int result = 0;
    while (w > 0)
    {
        ++result;
        w = w/10;
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", check_length(0));
    printf("%d\n", check_length(9));
    printf("%d\n", check_length(10));
    printf("%d\n", check_length(1234567890));
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
10
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This fixes the error.